# Cannot get Metro 3.0.13 to display in ASP.NET 5 MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, metro-ui-css

I have downloaded the Metro CSS via Bower by including it in the Bower.json file:

```
"metro-ui-css": "3.0.13"
```

This appears to install the Metro stuff under /wwwroot/lib/metro-ui-css/build/css and also /fonts and /less folders.
I have included the following references in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<environment names="Development">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/metro-ui-css/build/css/metro.css">
```

And under the `<head>` section::

```
<environment names="Development">
<script src="~/lib/metro-ui-css/build/js/metro.js"></script>
```

But no matter which Metro class I try to include in a View .cshtml file the Classes will not appear. Any idea what I am doing wrong and how I can get them to display?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a new Bundle**

In the 'App_Start' folder of your solution, find the 'BundleConfig.cs' file and open it. Here you can add a new bundle, for example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/metroJs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/metroJs.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/metroJs").Include(                        
                    "~/Content/metroJs.css"));
```

Your paths to the .js and .css files may be different, however this may also be correct.

Once you've done that, go back to your '_Layout.cshtml' file and at the bottom you'll more than likely already have some '@Scripts.Render()'. Just add one with the name of the new bundle you just created like so:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/metroJs")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/metroJs")
```

Comment: Hi,Unfortunately under ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 there is no App_Start folder and no BundleConfig.cs. They must have been moved somewhere else but I'm not sure where: any thoughts?

Comment: @JeremyBritton This answer/thread may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19038935/1489570

Comment: @MalvEarp You can't add a css file to a ScriptBundle (like you wrote in your answer). The css must go into a `StyleBundle` that will then be added with `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/whatever");

Comment: @MichaëlPolla Correct, I must not have been concentrating completely when writing the example.